# How to change the size width of UIImagePickerController on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

How to change the size width of `UIImagePickerController` on `iPad`? I can change the height so it is 700 but can't change width and it still 320.
My code.

```
 UIImagePickerController*  imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
 imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 imagePicker.delegate=self;
 CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(imagePicker.view.frame.origin.x, imagePicker.view.frame.origin.y, 720, 700);
 imagePicker.view.frame = myRect;
 self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
 myRect = CGRectMake(100, 880, 900, 900);
 CGRect re2 = CGRectMake(0,0,800,800);
 [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:re2.size];
 [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[self.view bounds] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:myRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];      
 [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:re2.size];
```

Comment: Why are you presenting the popover twice from 2 different rects? Also, it's not necessary to set the frame of imagePicker, since it's the content view controller of the popover, and its size will be set when you set the popover contentSize.

Answer (score 10):

I had your same problem and I solved with the UINavigationControllerDelegate, since the UIImagePickerView content for the PhotoLibrary is a navigatorController. When you select a row it changes ViewController and the size of the popover changes as well.
So, in your willShowViewController delegate just put:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(800, 800);
}
```

This will prevent the resizing of the popover.

Comment: Hi. I used your code to solve resizing problem. Solved. But now when I try to select image its tab positions are misplaced. When I tab on one image on its right side, next image is taped and selected. Please help..

Answer (score 3):

This simplified code worked fine for me:

```
    UIImagePickerController*  imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 880, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, 700)];
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that as soon as you select a row, the size changes back to 320. It is as if the imagePicker has been designed for iPhone.

Comment: @Srikanth, you should edit your question to add that fact -- that's a different problem from the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

*iOS 9 and above.*

Another way is it to use **ContainerViewController** and add UImagePickerViewController to ContainerViewController. overriding size in UINavigationControllerDelegate methods has its limits. (not possible to go down on height below 600pt)

```
    _imagePicker                      = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.delegate             = self;
    _imagePicker.sourceType           = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

    UIViewController *containerViewController    = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    containerViewController.preferredContentSize = _imagePicker.preferredContentSize;
    [containerViewController addChildViewController:_imagePicker];
    [containerViewController.view addSubview:_imagePicker.view];
    [_imagePicker didMoveToParentViewController:containerViewController];

    if (!_imagePickerPopover) {
        //customize PopoverController, use your own
        _imagePickerPopover = [[PopoverController alloc] init:cnt];
    }
```